# Microsoft/Ford Sync SDK

Tags: sdk, synchronization, smartdevicelink

Just got a car with the Microsoft sync system in it.  Did a quick search online and was curious if anyone is aware of any SDK that may exist, sample open source add-on applications, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hopefully the SDK won't need to be Fixed Or Repaired Daily, too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the SDK is coming very soon.  The story was just posted on Engadget:

http://www.engadget.com/2009/12/18/ford-to-give-sync-some-app-store-flavor-opening-api-to-devs-in/

Now just imagine what you could do with access to your automobile functionality!

Answer (score 3):

***UPDATE***:

Looks like [Ford has finally released their SDK](http://bits.blogs.nytimes.com/2013/01/08/c-e-s-2013-have-you-programmed-a-ford-lately/):

https://developer.ford.com/

---

Ford has a website [SYNC Mobile Application Developer Network](https://secure.syncmyride.com/Own/Modules/Developer/Subscribe.aspx) but the SYNC SDK does not look to be available yet (their site mentions possibly later this year). It appears they are stilling working on the API before releasing it.  All they are offering now is a way to register to be notified of new info as it becomes available.

From their [About page](http://www.syncmyride.com/Own/Modules/Developer/about.aspx):

> Ford is hard at work developing an API
>   to allow developers to integrate their
>   Smartphone applications with SYNC. The
>   Developer Program website will educate
>   developers about the Ford SYNC
>   platform and how to interact with it
>   via the API. There will be a full set
>   of documentation, example
>   applications, reference libraries, and
>   even a developer forum so you can
>   reach out to the community for quick
>   help.
>
> With the available SYNC API's, mobile
>   application developers will be able to
>   do some of the following:
>
> 1. Create a voice UI for your application using the in-vehicle
>      speech recognition system.
> 2. Write information to the radio head display or in-vehicle touchscreen
> 3. Speak text using text-to-speech engine.
> 4. Use the in-vehicle menu system to provide commands or options for
>      your mobile application
> 5. Get button presses from the radio and steering wheel controls.
> 6. Receive vehicle data (speed, GPS location, fuel economy, etc.)
>
> ***The official API and full website
>   launch is set to be targeted for later
>   this year.***

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any. Its a closed ecosystem.

http://www.autoblog.com/2009/01/09/ces-2009-sync-could-one-day-add-app-development-like-iphone/

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand it is based on the CE 6.0 platform using windows automotive 4.1, but I could be wrong. We really need a forum to get this going. Hurry up Ford! Release the SDK!

Given the way Windows automotive is there is only two ways of putting a ROM on Sync. Using JTAG to put your own custom bootloader (forget it), or though the USB. Which you will need to know how to sign the file so sync will think it is an OEM ROM. So at this point even if you were able to come up with your own custom rom by using Microsoft eMbedded Visual C++ you would still have no way to get it on there.

BTW, the SDK they are talking about releasing will only be to develop apps for applink. (not modifying the OS). However, to upload the apps we might be able to find out how to sign the .bin file for sync to accept a ROM through the USB.

Then again this is just from my understanding... I am no great developer or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Ford launched sdk in ces, check it out: http://techcrunch.com/2013/01/08/ford-launches-its-openxc-sdk-and-hardware-specs-to-let-developers-access-its-cars-sensors-and-metrics/